Undefined reference in VScode not able to solve it
When I run this code that is 1999C I am getting an error of giving this
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
My code
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int mian(){

int t;
cin>>t;

while(t-->0){
    int n,s,m;
    cin>>n>>s>>m;
    vector<pair<int,int>>t;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            int e1;
            int e2;
            cin>>e1>>e2;
            t.push_back({e1,e2});
    }
        string str="YES";
        if(abs(t[0].first)>=s){
            
            cout<<str<<endl;return 0;}

        if(abs(m-t[n-1].second)>=s){

            cout<<str<<endl;return 0;}

    for(int i=0;i<n-2;i++){

        if(abs(t[i].second-t[i+1].first)>=s)

        {cout<<str<<endl;return 0;}}



    cout<<"NO"<<endl;
    
}




    return 0;
}

but this code gives me
That I am able to compile my code and able to run it
